# Background StreamSocketListener just run one time

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a `StreamSocketListener` registered in a background task.

When it receives a request the `Run` method starts.

The first time it runs well, the second time I get that error:

> O identificador de objeto não representa um objeto válido. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800710D8)

The complete code is:

```
public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
{
    var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
    var details = (SocketActivityTriggerDetails)taskInstance.TriggerDetails;
    var socketInformation = details.SocketInformation;
    try
    {
        ShowToast(details.Reason.ToString());
        if (details.Reason == SocketActivityTriggerReason.ConnectionAccepted &&
            socketInformation.SocketKind == SocketActivityKind.StreamSocketListener)
        {
            using (IOutputStream output = socketInformation.StreamSocket.OutputStream)
            {
                string str = "Tudo certo\r\n";
                var conteudo = $"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: Close\r\nContent-Length: {str.Length}\r\n\r\n{str}";
                using (Stream stream = output.AsStreamForWrite())
                {
                    var bodyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(conteudo);
                    stream.Write(bodyArray, 0, bodyArray.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ShowToast(e.Message);
        StreamSocketListener socket = new StreamSocketListener();
        socket.EnableTransferOwnership(taskInstance.Task.TaskId, SocketActivityConnectedStandbyAction.DoNotWake);
        await socket.BindServiceNameAsync("8080");
        await socket.CancelIOAsync();
        socket.TransferOwnership("Teste");
    }
    deferral.Complete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the remarks of [`TransferOwnership`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket#Windows_Networking_Sockets_StreamSocket_TransferOwnership_System_String_) method of [`StreamSocket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocket) class:

> Your app should call this method to transfer ownership of the StreamSocket to the socket brokering service when the app is about to be suspended, or at the end of a background task

So at the end of your background you should call `TransferOwnership` method. You only call it in `catch` block, if your code snippet try succesfully it will not invoke `TransferOwnership`. You should be able also invoke the method at the last of `try` block or after try and catch finally to invoke this method to ensure transfer ownership of the `StreamSocket` to the socket brokering service.

I reproduced your issue on my side and resolved with adding `socket.TransferOwnership("Teste");` to the last of `try` block .

```
try
{
    ShowToast(details.Reason.ToString());
    if (details.Reason == SocketActivityTriggerReason.ConnectionAccepted &&
        socketInformation.SocketKind == SocketActivityKind.StreamSocketListener)
    {
        using (IOutputStream output = socketInformation.StreamSocket.OutputStream)
        {
            string str = "Tudo certo\r\n";
            var conteudo = $"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: Close\r\nContent-Length: {str.Length}\r\n\r\n{str}";
            using (Stream stream = output.AsStreamForWrite())
            {
                var bodyArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(conteudo);
                stream.Write(bodyArray, 0, bodyArray.Length);
            }
        }
    }
    socket.TransferOwnership("Teste");
}
```

More details please reference the [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SocketActivityStreamSocket).

Comment: The oficial sample just tell about StreamSocket, and not StreamSoketListener :(